# Woocommerce return product meta field for each by variation id

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api, woocommerce

If below returns the `external_varient_id` to the product `variation_id`

```
 $request['items'] [] = array(
 'external_variant_id' => $item['variation_id'] ? $item['variation_id'] : $item['product_id'],
```

How can I return the product meta field for `printful_variant_id` would I use something like `'variant_id'=> get_post_meta( $variation_id, 'printful_variant_id', true );` ?

For example the following uses a text version of the correct value I'm looking for, but it doesn't use a variable that's associated with the product `variation_id` for each `$item`

```
'variant_id'=> '4830',
```

Answer (score 0):

Initial testing is showing this as a possibility not sure if it is the best use case...

```
$valued = get_post_meta( $item['data']->get_id(), 'printful_variant_id', true),

             'variant_id'=> $valued,
```